# Can I send batched messages through a Websphere MQ Queue using Java JMS?

Tags: java, batch-file, jms, ibm-mq

I'm working in a project that requires to send multiple messages to another application via asynchronous Websphere MQ messages. Actually I'm opening and closing sessions for every message I send. I appreciate your answers. By the way this is my first post here.

Comment: Opening/closing sessions for each message creates unnecessary overhead; you can send a group of messages as batch based on comments below.

Answer (score 1):

In your question header, you mentioned the word **batched** which made me think you might want to send all the grouped messages in a single transaction so that all messages in the group are delivered or none at all. (An atomic send). If this is an important piece, I would slightly modify Friek's (clean and concise) code as follows:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(true, SESSION_TRANSACTED);
....
producer.send(msgOne);
producer.send(msgTwo);
session.commit();
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure something like this should work:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false, SESSION.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
// Create first message
Message msgOne = session.createTextMessage("Message One");
// Set reply-to queue to REPLY1QUEUE
msgOne.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue("REPLY1QUEUE"));
// Create another message.
Message msgTwo = session.createTextMessage("Message Two");
msgTwo.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue("REPLY2QUEUE"));

// Initialize destination queue and message producer.
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("DESTQUEUE"));

// Connect, send and close.
connection.start();
producer.send(msgOne);
producer.send(msgTwo);
connection.close();

// Close the session.
session.close();
```

If I'm not mistaken, the reply-to queue is optional.