# How to send messages to ibm mq transactionally

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022576/can-i-send-batched-messages-through-a-websphere-mq-queue-using-java-jms), but I dont know how to apply the answer to my program. I dont understand how to open session and send all messages in one transaction.

For now I call `JmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue", "message")` in a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are samples shipped with IBM MQ. Please refer them as starting point. The following example is modified from SimplePTP.java sample to send messages in a loop and then commit. There is createSession call with first parameter as `true` to start a transaction and there is `session.commit` to commit the transaction after all messages are sent.

```
try {
  // Create a connection factory
  JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
  JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

  // Set the properties
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
  cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
  cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM1");
  cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "SimplePTP (JMS)");

  // Create JMS objects
  connection = cf.createConnection();
  session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  destination = session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
  producer = session.createProducer(destination);

  // Start the connection
  connection.start();

  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
  TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP: Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);
  // And, send the message
  producer.send(message);
  System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);
  }
  session.commit();
}
catch (JMSException jmsex) {
}
```

Comment: There are additional samples in the ibmmq dev-patterns repo here > https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/transactions/JMS/SE <. Also this tutorial on transactions might be useful > https://developer.ibm.com/articles/an-introduction-to-local-transactions-using-mq-and-jms/ <

Comment: Something else to note for future readers is that the channel that production applications connect through should not be SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN. It is only used in the above answer for demonstration purposes. It's recommended to talk to your MQ admins & have a channel for your specific application created. This allows for the use of channel authentication (CHLAUTH) to restrict access to the channel, and also enforce various other security concepts (eg user mapping or user authentication, which then hooks into the Object Authority Manager (OAM), and so on).